# List all files inside a folder in a zip file in python

Tags: python, zip

I have a zip file structure like - B.zip/org/note.txt
I want to directly list the files inside org folder without going to other folders in B.zip

I have written the following code but it is listing all the files and directories available inside the B.zip file

```
f = zipfile.ZipFile('D:\python\B.jar')

for name in f.namelist():
    print '%s: %r' % (name, f.read(name))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the yields by startwith function.(Using Python 3)

```
import os
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('D:\python\B.jar') as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if filename.startswith("org"):
            print(filename)
```

Comment: What if i have one more dir  inside org like B.zip/org/new/note.txt

Comment: Instead of if filename.startswith("org"): use if filename.startswith("org/new"):

Answer (score 0):

To recursively list all files that are inside ZIP files of a certain folder:

```py
import os
import zipfile

# Use your folder path 
path = r'set_yoor_path'

for file in os.listdir(os.chdir(path)):
    if file[-3:].upper() == 'ZIP':
        for item in zipfile.ZipFile(file).namelist():
            print(item)
```